# Problems with python GRASS module setup outside GRASS

Tags: python, grass-7.0, grass.script

I currently have GRASS version 78 installed with my OSGEO4W. I am trying to utilize the boilerplate instructions [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/libpython/script.html#module-script.setup) to call the GRASS module in my python script outside of the GRASS console (ie in VS Code or Anaconda>Jupyter Notebook). When I try to run the following in VS Code, I get this error:

```
ERROR: MAPSET user1 not found at C:\Users\myuser\grassdata\nc_spm_08
{'GISDBASE': 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\grassdata', 'LOCATION_NAME': 'nc_spm_08', 'MAPSET': 'user1'}
ERROR: MAPSET user1 not found at C:\Users\myuser\grassdata\nc_spm_08
ERROR: MAPSET user1 not found at C:\Users\myuser\grassdata\nc_spm_08
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\myuser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\myuser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
run()
  File "c:\Users\myuser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Projects\TWI\TWI\scripts\grass_setup.py", line 73, in <module>
for rast in gscript.list_strings(type='raster'):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 1282, in list_strings
for line in read_command("g.list",
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 503, in read_command
return handle_errors(returncode, stdout, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 342, in handle_errors
raise CalledModuleError(module=None, code=code,
```

grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None g.list --q -m type=raster ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.

The main issue seems to be that MAPSET user1 is not found in myuser/grassdata folder (Note: I changed the actual folder name to `myuser` to protect my PII). Oddly when I tried to debug the script, the variable `rcfiled` was showing as `C:\\Users\\MYUSER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4sfb9ai1`. What am I doing wrong here? Note2: I don't have an `existing` Location or Mapset. I just added a folder called `grassdata`

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

# define GRASS Database
# add your path to grassdata (GRASS GIS database) directory
gisdb = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "grassdata")
# the following path is the default path on MS Windows
# gisdb = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents/grassdata")

# specify (existing) Location and Mapset
location = "nc_spm_08"
mapset = "user1"

# path to the GRASS GIS launch script
# we assume that the GRASS GIS start script is available and on PATH
# query GRASS itself for its GISBASE
# (with fixes for specific platforms)
# needs to be edited by the user
grass7bin = 'grass78'
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    # MS Windows
    grass7bin = r'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\grass78.bat'
    # uncomment when using standalone WinGRASS installer
    # grass7bin = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS 7.2.0\grass74.bat'
    # this can be avoided if GRASS executable is added to PATH
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    # Mac OS X
    # TODO: this have to be checked, maybe unix way is good enough
    grass7bin = '/Applications/GRASS/GRASS-7.2.app/'

# query GRASS GIS itself for its GISBASE
startcmd = [grass7bin, '--config', 'path']
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
except OSError as error:
    sys.exit("ERROR: Cannot find GRASS GIS start script"
         " {cmd}: {error}".format(cmd=startcmd[0], error=error))
if p.returncode != 0:
    sys.exit("ERROR: Issues running GRASS GIS start script"
         " {cmd}: {error}"
         .format(cmd=' '.join(startcmd), error=err))

if (type(out) == bytes):
    out = (out.decode("utf-8"))
    print(out)
    print(out.strip(os.linesep))
    gisbase = out.strip(os.linesep)
else:
    gisbase = out.strip(os.linesep)

# set GISBASE environment variable
os.environ['GISBASE'] = gisbase

# define GRASS-Python environment
grass_pydir = os.path.join(gisbase, "etc", "python")
sys.path.append(grass_pydir)

# import (some) GRASS Python bindings
import grass.script as gscript
import grass.script.setup as gsetup

# launch session
rcfile = gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)

# example calls
gscript.message('Current GRASS GIS 7 environment:')
print(gscript.gisenv())

gscript.message('Available raster maps:')
for rast in gscript.list_strings(type='raster'):
    print(rast)

gscript.message('Available vector maps:')
for vect in gscript.list_strings(type='vector'):
    print(vect)

# delete the rcfile
os.remove(rcfile)
```